# ESP8266 by AT commands doens't detect TCP closed connections

Tags: server, iot, microcontroller, esp8266

I'm developing a new firmware for an IoT device, one of its features is to create a WiFi SoftAP using an ESP8266. This new device is based on an old device firmware that I developed 4 years ago.

Now all works perfect until I close the WiFi in my phone; I remember that the old ESP8266 send a string like "**0,CLOSED**" witch means that the TCP device connected to the SoftAP has being disconnected; by that signal I can indicate with an LED if somebody is connected to the IoT device; but my currently ESP8266 only send that string after the TCP timeout is over.

There's different AT command firmwares for ESP8266?

I just need that the ESP send something to let my microcontroller knows that the TCP connection has being closed.

ESP firmware version:

AT version:0.40.0.0(Aug  8 2015 14:45:58)
SDK version:1.3.0
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.
Build:1.3.0.2 Sep 11 2015 11:48:04

Comment: that is normal. TCP connection has very long timeouts

Comment: @Juraj In my previous device that works different. When you close the TCP connection in the phone the WiFi module sends a 0,CLOSED to the serial port and the microcontroller knows that is nobody connected. Also, if you close the connection manually the protocol layer should send a connection closed to the WiFi module.

Comment: you write that you "close WiFi", which I understand as turning the WiFi off

Comment: @Juraj Exactly!

Comment: if you turn off WiFi the connections at TCP level are still up and waiting for packets arriving possibly over other network interface

Comment: @Juraj But the connection that was at "socket 0" is no longer available and when you ask the status to the ESP8266 says that somebody is connected from IP xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa , so, the only way to know is to ping that IP and check if somebody answer. That was not working like that.

Comment: the current NonOS SDK version is 3.0.5 with AT firmware version 1.7.5

Comment: @Juraj I'm looking this page and can't find that version https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/release-v2.2.0.0_esp8266/AT_Binary_Lists/ESP8266_AT_binaries.html

Comment: that is the IDF SDK with AT 2 for esp32 with deprecated support for esp8266.  not recommended. here https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/releases

Comment: My ESP8266 is the ESP01 "Ai-Cloud inside". Will it work with it? What is IDF?

Comment: sorry but for "What is" questions we have Internet search engines for more than 25 years now